# Why is my file with redirected stderr empty?

Tags: windows, io-redirection, openconnect

I am using OpenConnect 8.10 on Windows using binaries from https://github.com/horar/openconnect/releases/tag/v8.10

This is the output of `openconnect.exe`:

```
No server specified
 Usage:  openconnect [options] <server>
Open client for multiple VPN protocols, version v8.10

Using GnuTLS 3.6.13. Features present: PKCS#11, RSA software token, HOTP software token, TOTP software token, Yubikey OATH, System keys, DTLS, ESP
      --config=CONFIGFILE         Read options from config file
  -V, --version                   Report version number
  -h, --help                      Display help text

Set VPN protocol:
...
```

I want to redirect the complete output to a file. `openconnect.exe 1> openconnect.log` successfully redirects most of it to the file, leaving only

```
No server specified
```

on the screen. Also, `openconnect.exe 2> openconnect.log` removes that single line, leaving

```
Usage:  openconnect [options] <server>
Open client for multiple VPN protocols, version v8.10

Using GnuTLS 3.6.13. Features present: PKCS#11, RSA software token, HOTP software token, TOTP software token, Yubikey OATH, System keys, DTLS, ESP
      --config=CONFIGFILE         Read options from config file
  -V, --version                   Report version number
  -h, --help                      Display help text

Set VPN protocol:
...
```

However, the resulting file is empty! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I filed https://gitlab.com/openconnect/openconnect/-/issues/229

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/308184/i-o-redirection-using-cygwin-and-mingw